# -webkit-transform performance issues in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, google-chrome

We are using a jQuery plugin for some UI-effects. The plugin works great, but in chrome it melts the cpu's. The plugin tries to `css-transform` an image. Here is an image example:

```
<img width="1600" height="568" alt="" src="foo.png"  style="width: 1598px; height: 567px; left: -209px; top: -2px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: center top 0px; transition-duration: 0s; transform: scale(1);">
```

and here the code that is causing the problem in chrome ($img beeing an jQuery object):

```
$img.css({
    "-webkit-transition-duration":"20s",
    "-webkit-transition-timing-function":"ease",
    "-webkit-transform":"scale(0.73) rotate(0.1deg)",
    "-webkit-perspective":"0"
});
```

The problematic part is "`-webkit-transform`". In Firefox there is no performance problem with the equivalent CSS transformation.

Is this issue known, is there an alternative way doing it?

EDIT:

Using the 3d variant does not solve the problem here:

```
$img.css({
    "-webkit-transition-duration":"20s",
    "-webkit-transition-timing-function":"ease",
    "-webkit-transform":"scale3d(0.73,0.73,0.73) rotate3d(0,0,0,0.1deg)",
    "-webkit-perspective":"0"
});
```

EDIT2:

After looking more into the chrome devtools timeline, I can see lots of "Composite Layers" events (every 15ms). I also noticed (after enabling the FPS counter) that the framerate always is about 60 FPS when using the css transformation.

If I use a simple $.animate() to scale the image the FPS is around 20 max and there are less "Composite Layers" events (about every 40ms).

Looks like the heavy (re-)painting causes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use 3d transformations with the depth transform as the identity transformation to force the GPU to handle the operation instead of the CPU. Use `scale3d` and `rotate3d` instead of `scale` and `rotate`.

Answer (score 0):

To rorate images I use [jQueryRotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/), to scale you can change `width` and `height` of `img` tag with jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.
See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/FXXfd/) link.

```
$(document.body).ready(function(){
    $("img").mouseover(function(){
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        var toResize = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
        var newWidth = parseInt(width + toResize * width/height);
        var newHeight = parseInt(height + toResize * height/width);
        $(this).animate({
            width: newWidth + 'px',
            height: newHeight + 'px'
        }, 100, function(){
            //complete
        });
        var angle = Math.random() * 360;
        $(this).rotate({animateTo: angle});
    });
});
```